# RET after move-end-of-line in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

After an update, I'm no longer able to create a newline after the last org-heading

If I use `C-e`, it uses `org-end-of-line` and pressing `RET` just opens the heading.

If I use `M-x move-end-of-line`, the point goes after the org special character, but I can't press `RET` here, either. Nothing happens.

Any idea what I can try?;)

Comment: After what update? From what to what?

Comment: What does `C-h c RET` say?

Comment: RET (translated from <return>) runs the command newline

Comment: @Drew well, after changing distro to NixOS and bringing my emacs configuration over;)

Comment: In one of my Org mode buffers, `RET` is bound to `org-return`. I tried it with `emacs -Q` too and it says the same thing, Are you sure the mode is set correctly for the file in question?

Comment: ok, I got this when running inside the org buffer: RET (translated from <return>) runs the command org-return